# Add or remove editors in 1st protection in multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

good day! I have several sheets with 1 protection each, and I want to loop among these sheets and add or remove editors in their protections.

Initially, I have this code:

```
function AddOrRemove() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  var protection = allProtections[0];
  protection.removeEditors(['email1@gmail.com']);
  protection.addEditors(['email2@gmail.com']);
};
```

This removes `email1@gmail.com` while adds `email2@gmail.com` on the `ActiveSheet`, meaning I have to manually go to each sheet and run it from there. However, I want to automate the looping of sheets, and thus came up with this code:

```
function AddOrRemove() {
  var sheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4","Sheet5","Sheet6","Sheet7","Sheet8","Sheet9","Sheet10"];
  for (var i = 0 ; i = 15 ; i++){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var allProtections = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
    var protection = allProtections[0];
    protection.removeEditors(['email1@gmail.com']);
    protection.addEditors(['email2@gmail.com']);
  }
};
```

where `sheets` are all the sheet names I wan to run the code to. However, when trying to run it, I encounter this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getProtections" of null. (line 5, file "AddOrRemoveEditors")
```

I tried `Logger.log(sheets[i]);` just before the `var Spreadsheets` in the for loop, and it's logging "null". However, when I put `Logger.log(sheets[0]);` before the for loop, it's correctly returning K. I'm not quite sure what's missing here. I feel the logic behind the code should work, but maybe I'm missing something. Asking for advise on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function AddOrRemove() {
  var sheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4","Sheet5","Sheet6","Sheet7","Sheet8","Sheet9","Sheet10"];
  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){//modified
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[i]);//modified
    var allProtections = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
    var protection = allProtections[0];
    protection.removeEditors(['email1@gmail.com']);
    protection.addEditors(['email2@gmail.com']);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried the code and I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetByName in object SpreadsheetApp. (line 4, file "AddOrRemoveEditors")`. It maybe that SpreadsheetApp doesn't have the `getSheetByName` as function.

Comment: I retained the `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheets[i]);` and adapted the `for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++)` from your answer, and it worked. Thanks so much! Just to ask, how come setting that as i = 15 would not work? Thanks!

Comment: Yeh. I shouldn't have removed that.  There were only 10 sheets in your list and the last one is `sheets[sheets.length-1]`